# Concatenate a variable string on the same line of Html email body , Outlook VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I need to concatenate variable string `str` on the same line of email body (`Line1`).
I tried to add inside the string like that `&str` , But the output is just **&str** and not the values of str. 
Also If I added after `</p>"` ,then it adds values of str on the next line. 
Kindly How to fix this issue ?

```
Sub Send_Email()
 
    Dim objOutlookApp As New Outlook.Application
 
    Dim myEmail As Outlook.MailItem
     Set myEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      myEmail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
       myEmail.Display
'___________________
 
    Dim str As String: str = "My Text"
 
    Dim Strbody As String
 
    Dim Style As String: Style = "<p style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Georgia>"
    Dim Line1 As String: Line1 = "&emsp;&emsp; Attached file contains </p>" & str  'this add str on the next line
 
    Strbody = Style & Line1
 
    myEmail.HTMLBody = Strbody & myEmail.HTMLBody
 
End Sub
```

Comment: your string seems to be working correctly if your desired output is `<p style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Georgia>&emsp;&emsp; Attached file contains </p>My Text` perhaps something else with HTML.

Comment: Should you string included in the same paragraph (<p>-tag) as _Attached file contains_? The try: `"&emsp;&emsp; Attached file contains" & str & "</p>"`

Comment: @Shrotter ,It works correctly.You can post as an answer and kindly add explain why it didn't work with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html tag *p* is a paragraph. If you want to include a string variable into a paragraph, it should be located before the ending *</p>* tag.

```vb
Dim Style As String: Style = "<p style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Georgia>"
Dim Line1 As String: Line1 = "&emsp;&emsp; Attached file contains " & str & "</p>"
```